# Cannot format Carbon date

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I am having trouble formatting a Carbon date.

Here is my code:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$datePosted = Carbon::now();
$datePosted->toRssString();


DB::table('entries')->insert(
    array('body' => $request->body,
          'date_posted' => $datePosted)
);
```

According to [this](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) website, `toRssString()` should format the date as `Thu, 26 Oct 2017 20:09:59 -0500`. However it is being put into the database in this format `2017-10-26 20:09:59`

Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

Comment: What is the column schema in the database? If it's date time, then that is the correct format.

Comment: @aynber It was on Varchar right now but datetime gave the same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign result to some variable and then pass it:

```
$result = $datePosted->toRssString();
```

Or you can do it directly in array:

```
array('body' => $request->body,
      'date_posted' => $datePosted->toRssString())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$datePosted = Carbon::now();

DB::table('entries')->insert(
    array('body' => $request->body,
          'date_posted' => $datePosted->toRssString())
);
```